# Words and their occurences in table column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a column (varchar) which contains words separated by '-'. 
**Table example:**

| id | slug |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1-name2-name3-name4-name5 |
| 2 | name6-name2-name3-name4-name7 |

What is the best way to count words and their occurences? 
 
**Expected result:**

| word | count |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 |
| name2 | 2 |
| name3 | 2 |
| name4 | 2 |
| name5 | 1 |
| name6 | 1 |
| name7 | 1 |

I tried this query, which works fast on a table with over 220 thousands records, but not sure if this is correct one (counts correctly or not)

```
  SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(slug,'-',-1) AS word,
  count(SUBSTRING_INDEX(slug,'-',-1)) as count 
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY word
```

Comment: Replace dashes with commas and use LOCATE() or INSTR() in joining condition. If you have no words list then convert your data to JSON array, then parse and aggregate.

Comment: Exactly 5 words?  Then SQL might be able to do it.  If if is a variable number, it gets lots messier; suggest doing it in app code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT,  slug VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'name1-name2-name3-name4-name5'),
(2, 'name6-name2-name3-name4-name7');
```

```
SELECT jsontable.word, COUNT(*) amount
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    CONCAT('["', REPLACE(test.slug, '-', '","'), '"]'),
           '$[*]' COLUMNS (word VARCHAR(16) PATH '$')) jsontable
GROUP BY jsontable.word;
```

| word | amount |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 |
| name2 | 2 |
| name3 | 2 |
| name4 | 2 |
| name5 | 1 |
| name6 | 1 |
| name7 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qAnwJSK4)

Comment: Thank you, works pretty fast )

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way would be to *properly Normalise* your data.

```
select * 
from table1 ; 

+----+-------+
| id | name  | 
+----+-------+
|  1 | name1 |
|  1 | name2 |
|  1 | name3 |
|  1 | name4 |
|  1 | name5 |
|  2 | name6 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  2 | name3 |
|  2 | name4 |
|  2 | name7 |
+----+-------+
```

Then, your requirement becomes a simple "group by" query:

```
select 
  name
, count( * ) tally 
from table1 
group by name 
order by name ; 

+-------+-------+
| name  | tally | 
+-------+-------+
| name1 |     1 |
| name2 |     2 |
| name3 |     2 |
| name4 |     2 |
| name5 |     1 |
| name6 |     1 |
| name7 |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```